# Is it possible to read all the rows in .xls file that where uploaded in drive using google drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have list of .xls files in google drive and now i want to read each file for specific data inside that files!! is it possible using drive API's?

Comment: How about this method? Unfortunately, .xls of Microsoft Excel cannot directly read and retrieve data using Google APIs. But it can be converted to Spreadsheet using Drive API. So by using this, after the file was converted to Spreadsheet, it retrieves data from it.

Answer (score 0):

Drive API doesn't directly work with .xls files since it's from Micrsoft Excel. You have to open  the .xls in your Google Drive through Google Sheet (right click, Open With -> Google Sheets). After that, Google Drive will make a copy of that file in a Google Spreadsheet version which you can work on, so you will notice there are two of those files in your Google Drive.

To work on that google-spreadsheet version, use Sheets API v4. Checkout [Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values).